# Taking screenshot of NGLView (NineVehGL engine)

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am using NinevehGL 3D engine http://nineveh.gl/

I want to get screenshot of OpenGL object. Problem is with below code

```
-(UIImage *) screenshot
{

// Capture screen here... and cut the appropriate size for saving and uploading
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([self theNGLView].bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// crop the area you want
CGRect rect;
rect = CGRectMake(0, 10, 300, 300);    // whatever you want
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
return img;  
}
```

Only background comes in screenshot but not actual NGLView or OpenGL object which is drawn on top of it.

I am using iOS SDK 6.0

Answer (score 0):

tried using

```
[[self the NGLView].layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

?

Comment: Yes mate it gives background only same as before

Comment: look for https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1704/_index.html call the method with the nglview as parameter

Comment: @mann According to the link Jerome Diaz gave, it mentions undefined results in an implementation that does not have a retained back-buffer. This was the first thing that came to mind when I read this question, try flushing the GL pipeline and then copying the pixels (BEFORE swapping/presenting buffers).

Comment: How can i do that? also the link which he gave there glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, _colorRenderbuffer);
 i got error there undeclared identifier GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES

Comment: Just to mention above code works fine in iOS SDK 5 or earlier. but not iOS SDK 6 or on iPhone 4

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this [link](http://nineveh.gl/community/forum/ios_6_bug_and_fix_nglview_drawtoimage), you need to download the latest NinevehGL SDK for iPhone5/iOS 6 which is provided in their [twitter link](https://twitter.com/ninevehgl/status/248363495903604737).

Comment: Thanks for the comment but i've already updated NinevehGL SDK and checked that link too.